Why isn't the datetime index used?
I've a big log table with about ~60m records for the past 2-3 years. The structure is like this:
CREATE TABLE `dmsserver_status_log` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thread_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `level_int` smallint(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `level_name` varchar(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (case `level_int` when 600 then 'TRACE' when 500 then 'DEBUG' when 400 then 'INFO' when 300 then 'WARN' when 200 then 'ERROR' when 100 then 'FATAL' when 0 then 'OFF' end) VIRTUAL,
  `logger_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `source_host` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `message` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `stacktrace` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `mdc` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `origin` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `client_uuid` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_login` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_code` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;


ALTER TABLE `dmsserver_status_log`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  ADD KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  ADD KEY `customer_id_2` (`customer_id`,`timestamp`),
  ADD KEY `timestamp_logger-name` (`timestamp`,`logger_name`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `id_with_origin` (`customer_id`,`origin`);


ALTER TABLE `dmsserver_status_log`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


ALTER TABLE `dmsserver_status_log`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dmsserver_status_log_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

If I try to query this table and want to see all loge since the last month mariadb does a full search over the whole table which takes very long time to execute (20+ Minutes):
EXPLAIN SELECT
    id,
    `timestamp`,
    level_name,
    [...]
FROM dmsserver_status_log
WHERE `timestamp` > '2024-08-01 00:00:00';

Result:
|id |select_type|table               |type|possible_keys                  |key|key_len|ref|rows    |Extra      |
|---|-----------|--------------------|----|-------------------------------|---|-------|---|--------|-----------|
|1  |SIMPLE     |dmsserver_status_log|ALL |timestamp,timestamp_logger-name|   |       |   |63087085|Using where|

And even if I try to force mariadb to use my 'timestamp' index it still won't use it:
EXPLAIN SELECT
    id,
    `timestamp`,
    level_name,
    [...]
FROM dmsserver_status_log USE INDEX (timestamp)
WHERE `timestamp` > '2024-08-01 00:00:00';

result:
|id |select_type|table               |type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows    |Extra      |
|---|-----------|--------------------|----|-------------|---|-------|---|--------|-----------|
|1  |SIMPLE     |dmsserver_status_log|ALL |timestamp    |   |       |   |63087600|Using where|

What I'm doing wrong here?

Ensure that the amount of matched rows is not more than 5% of total rows number. If so then: 1) Try not USE INDEX but FORCE INDEX. 2) Try to add upper date boundary - WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2024-08-01' AND '2024-09-04'.

Great thanks! FORCE INDEX was the key to success here. Instead of 20+ Minutes the query only takes seconds now...

FWIW, I would assume if you added all the columns you're selecting to your index (after the key field), the query would've naturally used it without you having to force it. E.g. ADD KEY timestamp (timestamp, id, level_name, [...])

@Akina - In my experience, it is more like 20%, not 5%.

These are redundant and can be dropped:  KEY customer_id (customer_id),
and KEY timestamp (timestamp),
